# Can I run .NET Core Application under a .NET 4.6/7 Site vise vera

Tags: iis, .net-core

I new to .NET Core and our IIS configuration is as so.  We run a single web site with about 70 .NET 4+ applications under it, each app runs under is own user and app pool.  Our developers have requested .NET Core to begin upgrading applications.

The site is not accessible, only the applications.  The applications do not inherit from the site web.config (which is generic) they pull from their own.

Would it be better to upgrade the site to .NET Core and then upgrade the apps, or leave the site at .NET 4 and upgrade the apps to .NET Core?

Comment: ASP.NET Core can work quite well with reverse proxy. Thus, host your .NET Framework/.NET Core sites separately and use a reverse proxy server to bridge the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Net Standard, you should be able to use code across all projects.. Ensure your Net Framework projects are on the latest version and you should be fine. I believe you use code from Net Core projects in Framework, but not the other way round